# Is there an alternative way to install dependencies for an Alexa Skill (requirements.txt is troublesome)?

Tags: python, pip, alexa-skills-kit, requirements.txt

I'm trying to develop an Alexa Skill which uses MechanicalSoup to scrape some data from a web search. My code works but I'm unable to install MechanicalSoup via the 'requirements.txt' file. I've even added all of MechanicalSoup's dependencies, like so:

```
boto3==1.9.216
ask-sdk-core==1.11.0
requests==2.25.1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
lxml==4.9.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
urllib3==1.26.9
certifi==2022.5.18.1
chardet==4.0.0
idna==2.10
mechanicalsoup==1.2.0
```

but I'm having no luck.

My events log looks like this:
[image]

Do you have any idea what I can do to get this to work? Is there a way to install directly with `pip install`, if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: How did you generate the `requirements.txt` file? Did you do it manually?

Comment: @StonedTensor The requirements.txt file is already included in the Alexa Skill Development Environment, I just added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

- your requirements.txt doesn't work? you could try to `pip install -r requirements.txt` on your computer, to see if the requirements actually work
- Your build server builds with a different version of python then your computer? for example, you could have `python 3.10`, while alexa has `python 2.7`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go and see if I can get it to work. I though Alexa used Python 3